# Im geeting an error while reading a file in opencv

Tags: opencv

Im reading am image file in cv2 with the extension .img but it is throwing this error :

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Please can I get the solution on this

This is my code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(r'D:\DATASET\aoi3.img')
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does the file exist? What is an ".img" file? Check here for supported formats. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gab32ee19e22660912565f8140d0f675a8

Comment: I am not familiar with .img file extension, and it doesn't seem to be one of the supported formats in opencv (see the documentation link in the comment above).